# How to deploy an app with a debug token on blackberry playbook?

Tags: blackberry-webworks, blackberry-playbook, blackberry-10

I can`t deploy an unsigned bar to my playbook device , because the of : failure 881 application author does not match debug token author. How can I fix this ?
I`ve installed a debug token with bb10 sdk, so on my device, in my Security >> Development Mode tab I have:
Debug Token .......    Installed
  Valid ............   Yes
  Author............   - 
  Expiration Thu Jan 17 2013 04:19:43 PM

I`ve tryed to deploy like 2 times with/without  tags

config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<widget xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets"
xmlns:rim="http://www.blackberry.com/ns/widgets"
version="1.0.0.0"
>

<name>AppDev2.0</name>
<author>-</author> <!-- and without <></> and still pops me the failure 881 author problem -->
<icon src="assets/icon.png"/>

<content src="index.html"/>

<rim:permissions>
    <rim:permit>access_location_services</rim:permit>
</rim:permissions>

<!-- for flickr search data (json) -->
<access uri="http://api.flickr.com" />
<!-- for flickr images from farm1. to farm9.  -->
<access uri="http://staticflickr.com/" subdomains="true" />

<!-- for google image search data (json) -->
<access uri="https://ajax.googleapis.com" />
<!-- for google images from t0. to t3. -->
<access uri="http://gstatic.com" subdomains="true"/>

<!-- for weather data (xml) from free. and icons from www. -->
<access uri="http://worldweatheronline.com/" subdomains="true"/>

<!-- used to create dialogs (location-details.js, splash.js, saved-locations.js-->
<feature id="blackberry.ui.dialog"/>
<!-- to enable the application to invoke the browser -->
<feature id="blackberry.invoke"/>
<!-- to trap the onswipedown event -->
<feature id="blackberry.app"/>

</widget>
```

Comment: Is this a webworks app, you have the webworks tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had similar issue. and **it was not an "author" problem** : I was trying to deploy in debug mode and the debugToken was just not installed on the device.

The debugToken must be on the device so that the deploy can work. You can upload the debugToken with :

```
blackberry-deploy -installDebugToken debugtoken.bar -device 169.254.0.1 -password
```

hope this helps :)

Answer (score 3):

"I had similar issue. Check that in blackbery-tablet.xml and fields are correct.

To get the right values for those fields just rename your packed .bar file to .zip, then unarchieve it. There will be manifest.mf file in META-INF folder. Open it with notepad. Grab and values from there and rebuild your app. If that does not help, then rebuild debug token and make sure you install it on the device. Debug token needs to have correct device pin.

Please click the Thumbs Up icon if this comment has helped you! If your issue is resolved, please click the solution button on the resolution!" -source http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Web-and-WebWorks-Development/Failure-881-Application-Author-does-not-match-debug-token-author/m-p/2055935#M32567

Comment: Also a .bar file is just a .zip archive

Answer (score 0):

The value of the author tag must match your company name you have provided during creation of BlackBerry Signing keys.

Answer (score 0):

Open with a text editor the file `blackberry-tablet.xml`, the file is inside your `<BlackBerry WebWorks SDK Tablet install folder>\bbwp\AirAppTemplates\src\`.

You should see a section with something like:

```
<publisher>Sample Inc.</publisher>
<category>core.internet</category>
```

after this section you have to add

```
<author>*replace with your author name info*</author>
<authorId>*replace with your author id info*</authorId>
```

You'll have to get your author and your author id info from the debug token that you uploaded on your PlayBook. You should have your debug token on your computer, rename .bar to .zip and extract. With a text editor look in the META-INF folder at the MANIFEST.MF file for values for `Package-Author:` and `Package-Author-Id:` folowed by the actual string values.

Hope this helps.